# Spark HashingTF result explanation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I tried standard spark HashingTF example on DataBricks.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer}

val sentenceData = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0, "Hi I heard about Spark"),
  (0, "I wish Java could use case classes"),
  (1, "Logistic regression models are neat")
)).toDF("label", "sentence")

val tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("sentence").setOutputCol("words")
val wordsData = tokenizer.transform(sentenceData)
val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
  .setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("rawFeatures").setNumFeatures(20)
val featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)
display(featurizedData)
```

I have diffuculty in understanding result below.
[Please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj317.png) 
When numFeatures is 20

```
[0,20,[0,5,9,17],[1,1,1,2]]
[0,20,[2,7,9,13,15],[1,1,3,1,1]]
[0,20,[4,6,13,15,18],[1,1,1,1,1]]
```

If [0,5,9,17] are hash values
and [1,1,1,2] are frequencies.
17 has frequency 2
9 has 3 (it has 2)
13,15 have 1 while they must have 2.

Probably I am missing something. Could not find documentation of detailed explanation.

Comment: Spark class **HashingTF** utilizes the hashing trick.
A raw feature is mapped into an index (term) by applying a hash function. Then term frequencies are calculated based on the mapped indices. This approach avoids the need to compute a global term-to-index map, which can be expensive for a large corpus, but it suffers from potential hash collisions, where different raw features may become the same term after hashing.

Answer (score 1):

As mcelikkaya notes, the output frequencies are not what you would expect. This is due to hash collisions for a small number of features, 20 in this case. I have added some words to the input data (for illustration purposes) and upped features to 20,000, and then the correct  frequencies are produced:

```
+-----+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|label|sentence                                                 |words                                                                    |rawFeatures                                                                           |
+-----+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|0    |Hi hi hi hi I i i i i heard heard heard about Spark Spark|[hi, hi, hi, hi, i, i, i, i, i, heard, heard, heard, about, spark, spark]|(20000,[3105,9357,11777,11960,15329],[2.0,3.0,1.0,4.0,5.0])                           |
|0    |I i wish Java could use case classes spark               |[i, i, wish, java, could, use, case, classes, spark]                     |(20000,[495,3105,3967,4489,15329,16213,16342,19809],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|
|1    |Logistic regression models are neat                      |[logistic, regression, models, are, neat]                                |(20000,[286,1193,9604,13138,18695],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])                             |
+-----+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Your guesses are correct:

- 20 - is a vector size
- first list is a list of indices
- second list is a list of values

Leading 0 is just an artifact of internal representation.

There is nothing more here to learn.

Comment: Dear cricket , Thanks for answer. If second list for values( i assume it is frequencies). Do not you see any abnormal value in frequencies? How could 17 have frequency 2?

Comment: @mcelikkaya, I asked this same question at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311260/understanding-and-interpreting-the-output-of-sparks-tf-idf-implementation/312259#312259) and posted my findings in case it helps. Thanks!